# Rename a page during jekyll build

Tags: jekyll

I would like to rename a file denoted as `someFancyPage.md` to `index.md` during `jekyll build`.
However, the file needs to remain in the same directory.

So far I tried `permalink`, which however seems to be always interpreting the value as absolute.

I would like to use this behavior, as I created a plugin, which executes on folders containing `someFancyPage.md` and does some magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that using *pure* `jekyll`, you'd have to use the `permalink` and set it in each page to a path with the same name of the folder. That would cause the generated page to be `index.html`.

For example, imagine you have a structure like this:

```
/404.html
/index.html
/folder-01/someFancyPage.md
/folder-02/someFancyPage.md
```

In the front matter, you declare the `permalink` to be the full path of the folder, without the file name. For example:

> /folder-01/someFancyPage.md

```
---
layout: page
title: Folder 01
permalink: /folder-01/
---

This is folder 01
```

---

> /folder-02/someFancyPage.md

```
---
layout: page
title: Folder 02
permalink: /folder-02/
---

This is folder 02
```

This will rename these pages the way you're looking for.

---

Note: Because you're overriding the permalink, the name of the physical folders in the file system is irrelevant. If you have `/dennis/someFancyPage.md` but override the permalink to `/folder-01/` then `jekyll` will honor that and create `/folder-01/index.html`

Comment: Would be an option, but I dont like duplicating this information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I adopted works (it is not really nice) uses information of the front matter while the filename remains `index.md`:

```
---
layout: picture-gallery
---
```

In my plugin, I search now for the pages, which have this layout.
add a custom front matter (in my case the `layout` is used).

```
    def generate(site)
        paginator_directories = Array.new
        pages do |sf|
            #next unless sf.respond_to?(:layout)
            #This is a workaround to check if "layout: picture-gallery" is set.
            next unless File.readlines(sf.path).grep(/picture\-gallery/).size > 0

            paginator_directories.insert(-1, File.dirname(sf.path))
        end

        #Do some really fancy magic here.
   end
```