# Jekyll copy a folder to another folder at build time

Tags: jekyll

I have multiple language versions of my website from the root folder as

```
en-ca/* 
fr-ca/* 
en-us/*
```

etc.

I have created a `_resources` folder that contains css common to all sites.

I would like to copy the content of the `_resources` folder into `en-ca/*`, `fr-ca/*`, `en-us/*`, etc. at build time.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmmm.... Are you sure you want to do that? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

If the CSS is identical across the different languages, why would you make the end-users download the same file again when switching to a different language, if they already have the same file cached in their browser?

It would be better to have the common CSS in a single place, and have your HTML templates reference that instead, and leverage the browser cache, etc.

---

Anyway, to answer your question, if you want to use pure Jekyll (without a plugin), you can create empty `common.css` files inside each language folder, and use the tag `include_relative` to copy the contents of the `common.css` to it.

> **Jekyll Includes / include_relative**
>
> https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file

---

Alternatively, you can write a plugin that copies the file to the folders you want. In the answer below there's a small example of a plugin that renames files... You can adapt it to copy files instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600246/211672